# Why does the author define these "logical notations" for set logic with "if then" and &?

Tags: logic, notation, quantifiers

In Section 1.1 of ["Set Theory for Computer Science"](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~gw104/STfCS2010.pdf), the author defines

$ \forall x \in X. P(x) $ and $ \exists x \in X.P(x) $ as shorthand for

$ \forall x.(x \in X \Rightarrow P(x)) $ and $ \exists x.(x \in X \space \& \space P(x)) $, respectively.

The author's explanation of these shorthand notations in English ("for all x in X, P(x)") make sense to me, but I'm not really sure where the "if-then" $ \Rightarrow $ and "and" $ \& $ come in.

Comment: Your copied it wrong.

Comment: It's not $\forall x\in X\implies P(x)$, it's $\forall x. x\in X\implies P(x)$. For all $x$, if $x\in X$ then $P(x)$. Same goes for the other one.

Comment: To be even clearer, I've added parentheses: $$\forall x\in X.P(x)$$ is shorthand for $$\forall x.(x\in X\implies P(x))$$

Comment: The main reason for the shorthand is that it is very common form, and it makes things clearer.

Comment: For example, humans tends to say, "Every $x$ in collection $X$ has property $P$." But that isn't a legal construct in formal logic. It can be formalized as "For every $x$, if $x$ is in $X$ then $x$ has property $P$." That's a longer sentence, and obscures the intuitive meaning, so we prefer the shorter sentence.

Comment: Fixed incorrect figures - thanks.

Comment: @Thomas: More accurately, it's not a legal construct in a minimalist version of formal logic, although it is legal in more user-friendly versions (e.g. by making the definition the OP is asking about!). Actually, in some versions of formal set theory, *unbounded* quantification is strictly illegal: all quantifiers must be bound. i.e. it is legal to write $\forall x \in X: P(x)$ but not $\forall x: x \in X \implies P(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that quantifiers are taken over the entire universe of discourse. So to limit the quantifier to a certain set you need to somehow "filter" out the set of objects being quantified.

When you quantify with $\forall x$, then you want to say given any $x$, then I don't care if $x\notin X$, but if $x\in X$ then I want to assure that $P(x)$. This is exactly to say $\forall x(x\in X\rightarrow P(x))$, and that's why this is defined to be the meaning of $\forall x\in X.P(x)$.

When you quantify with $\exists x$, then you want to say that there exists an object $x$ satisfying $P$ which happens to be an element of $X$ as well. And this happens to be exactly the meaning of $\exists x(x\in X\land P(x))$. So this is how we define $\exists x\in X. P(x)$.

Comment: The other places you will see this is, say, $\forall x\neq \emptyset\dots$ or $\forall d\mid n\dots$ or other conditionals that start with the variable. We don't otherwise write $\forall Q(x):P(x)$, because it is less clear what variable is being referenced.

Comment: This makes sense. I had (somehow) forgot the whole point of these shorthands was to filter down the universe to a specified set. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

This is math's version of "typed" versus "untyped" objects.

In set theory, an unbound variable is essentially an untyped object. Or if you prefer, an object of type `Set`, the type "everything" has. Compare with the type `Object` from java.

But we can bind variables to other types; the most typical case is when we have a set, and we want to bind the object to a set. e.g we say "let $x$ be a real number" to introduce a new variable $x$ that is *bound* to the set $\mathbb{R}$. We might say that $\mathbb{R}$ is the *type* of $x$.

Quantifiers like $\forall x$ introduce variables, but this form introduces an unbound variable (or a variable of type `Set`, if you prefer). The notation $\forall x \in X$ introduces the variable $x$ and binds it to $X$ at the same time.

And it turns that $\forall x \in X : P(x)$ and $\forall x : x \in X \implies P(x)$ have the same semantics, so it is not unreasonable to *define* the former as meaning the latter.

As an aside, those who prefer typed logic might prefer to write $\forall x \in \mathbf{Set}: P(x)$ rather than $\forall x: P(x)$.